# Redirect WordPress homepage to newest Article

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I am trying to redirect my WordPress homepage to the newest article automatically.
At the moment I use a redirect suggested by Spencer Cameron

```
function redirect_homepage() {
    if( ! is_home() && ! is_front_page() )
        return;

    wp_redirect( 'http://homepage.com/article1', 301 );
    exit;
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_homepage' );
```

Now if I post article 2 I want the homepage to automatically connect to article 2 without me adjusting the functions.php.

I want no user to see the `www.example.com` but only the article, so there is always a redirect to the newest article when visiting the page.

However:
I want to have the possibility to still access `www.example.com/article1` (by manually typing the url) even if there is already `www.example.com/article2`.

How could I achieve that goal?

Comment: Why not just show the first post on your homepage as a "featured article" or something? Having your homepage redirect is bad for user experience because you're delaying page load time.

Comment: Not possible in this case, I dont want users to see the wordpress theme, but only use wordpress for a certain plugin.

Comment: That still doesn't make any sense... The way you're setting this up, no one will ever see the homepage of your site.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in [Get the ID of the latest post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/27882/12615): do a simple query to get one post (ordered by latest by default), then grab its permalink and redirect.

[Don't put this type of code in functions.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615), create your own mini-plugins to do it. If you want to disable this, it's just a matter of disabling a plugin, and not of editing a file.

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Redirect Homepage */

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_homepage' );

function redirect_homepage() 
{
    if( ! is_home() && ! is_front_page() )
        return;

    // Adjust to the desired post type
    $latest = get_posts( "post_type=post&numberposts=1" );
    $permalink = get_permalink( $latest[0]->ID );

    wp_redirect( $permalink, 301 );
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out brasofilo. TO be honest: I have no experience with mini plugins, followed the solution of a friend which works out perfectly for my scenario. No delays and no stress. Thanks!

Comment: The only experience needed is copy the code in a PHP file, upload it to the plugins folder and activate.

Answer (score 0):

A solution from a friend:
Replace index.php in the template folder with the following:

```
<?php global $query_string; query_posts($query_string.'&posts_per_page=1');  ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php header('Location: '.get_permalink()); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Thanks for helping me out